# Highcharts Treegraph: How to prevent node expand/collapse default click behavior in React?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts in React and unable to prevent the default expand/collapse click behaviors for the treegraph nodes. I tried a few methods, but nothing worked. Please see code snippet below for details on what I've tried. I've tried all the combinations between allPointSelect and the click properties.[image]

```js
const series = [{
  type: "treegraph",
  data: [...],
  // I've tried setting allowPointSelect to true in combination 
  // with the point.event.click e.preventDefault() 
  // and returning false without success. 
  // I've also left allowPointSelect false without any success.
  allowPointSelect: true,
  point: {
    events: {
      click: (e) => {
        //I've tried different combinations of the 2 lines below without success
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no option in Highcharts allows to prevent the expand/collapse functionality from happening. To make it work you need to write a wrap.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts._modules['Series/Treegraph/TreegraphPoint.js'].prototype, 'toggleCollapse', function(proceed, a, flag) {
 if (flag) {
  proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
 }
});
```

Docs:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/05m2sjcL/

Comment: How do I implement this in React?